# Games graphics appear incorrect while on HDMI

Tags: graphics-card, call-of-duty-ghosts

I play games on my Dell XPS laptop, All games are running normal graphics, no lags or freezing and everything is okay but the problem comes when I connect the laptop to my TV through the HDMI. Games graphics appear incorrect as if they are running in negative mode. Any suggestions?

[image: Call of Duty Ghosts]

Comment: Have you tried a second HDMI cable?  You might also want to check the driver version you've got and see if you can update it.  Does this show up outside of games, or only when you play games?

Comment: Yes, I have three HDMI slots in the TV, I tried them all and installed the latest driver update for my NVIDIA card. Thanks for your reply @agent86

Comment: This shows up in games and videos only. @agent86

Comment: Have you tried an actual spare cable? The issue could be the HDMI cable itself.

Comment: Do you have any other ports on you pc? like VGA? if the same behavior continues with a different port you can at least rule out the cables. What resolution does you PC have vs your TV's?

Comment: No, Actually I didn't try other cable yet.  I will try and come back with the result. Thank you @Kendra

Comment: Unfortunately, I have only the HDMI port in my laptop, It works with resolution 1366x768 as recommended by the laptop. I tried different resolutions but they all came up with the same result. Thank you @George

Comment: No worries :) you can try to duplicate the screen (short-key Windows+P) Do you get the same result? On the TV try finding out if there is a option how to change the fill-level if you know what i mean ;)

Comment: Actually I don't know what fill-level means to be honest, I did tried to duplicate but it shows a black screen on both laptop and TV. The only way works is the projector only option, It works very well with everything except videos and games. @George

Comment: The "Fill-Level" was something i just said. I don't know the real name for it. I just know that with my old laptop the TV was black until i clicked a button called "SCREEN" on my TV-controll

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a 25 pin plugin this enables a stronger connection with the tv and the system you are connecting it too , like when I had my ps3 I plugged it into one slot at the back of my Panasonic TV and it was black and white and had no sound , but when I used a different plugin it worked fine , so it's either 25 pin or you can try a different plugin , it might be the tv itself but I doubt it .